# Using bold text in remote view

Tags: java, android, text, bold

```
 //Setting our own layout for notification (instead of the regular android notification)
            RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.new_event_notification);
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventName,  eventToDisplay.getName());

            DateTime todayDate = new DateTime().now();


            //If the event's date equal to today's date
            if ((Days.daysBetween(eventToDisplay.getEventDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay(),todayDate.withTimeAtStartOfDay()).getDays())==0)
            {
                SpannableString eventDayOfTheWeekTxt= new SpannableString("Today");
                eventDayOfTheWeekTxt.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),0,4,0);
                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDayOfTheWeekTxt, eventDayOfTheWeekTxt+ "(" + eventToDisplay.getEventDate().dayOfWeek().getAsText() + ")");

            }
```

I'm trying to make the word "today" bold, and I found something in this forum as you can see... But it didn't work.

EDITED CODE:

```
 //If the event's date equal to today's date
            if ((Days.daysBetween(eventToDisplay.getEventDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay(),todayDate.withTimeAtStartOfDay()).getDays())==0)
            {
                SpannableString eventDayOfTheWeekTxt= new SpannableString("Today");
                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDayOfTheWeekTxt, eventDayOfTheWeekTxt+ "(" + eventToDisplay.getEventDate().dayOfWeek().getAsText() + ")");
                eventDayOfTheWeekTxt.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 4, 0);


            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are removing the spans via your concatenation. Either use `TextUtils.concat()` instead of `+`, or apply your `BOLD` span *after* the string concatenation.

---

In Java programming, concatenation creates new objects.

Replace:

```
SpannableString eventDayOfTheWeekTxt= new SpannableString("Today");
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDayOfTheWeekTxt, eventDayOfTheWeekTxt+ "(" + eventToDisplay.getEventDate().dayOfWeek().getAsText() + ")");
eventDayOfTheWeekTxt.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 4, 0);
```

with:

```
SpannableStringBuilder eventDayOfTheWeekTxt=new SpannableStringBuilder("Today");

eventDayOfTheWeekTxt.append("(");
eventDayOfTheWeekTxt.append(eventToDisplay.getEventDate().dayOfWeek().getAsText());
eventDayOfTheWeekTxt.append(")");
eventDayOfTheWeekTxt.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 4, 0);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDayOfTheWeekTxt, eventDayOfTheWeekTxt);
```

Comment: I have edited the post, I tried to apply the bold span after the concatenation... Didn't work for some reason.

Comment: @TalBarda: You need to apply the bold span to the value that you are putting in `setTextViewText()`. You are not doing that.

Comment: I don't understand... I applied it on eventDayOfTheWeekTxt which is in the setTextViewText()... What is the problem?

Comment: @TalBarda: "I applied it on eventDayOfTheWeekTxt which is in the setTextViewText()" -- no, you did not. See the updated answer.